# Profile view of ArcMap is outside of screen?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I need to get profile from my Lidar data. I normally use las data set profile view.
I don't know what happened and the profile view window is outside of my screen(I can just see the top part of profile view at the bottom of my screen). i have tried everything but so far no success.  I have added the snapshot for more detail. I just used window button and arrow key to move the window to the right then it happened
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Can you include a picture and the precise steps that you have performed since starting ArcMap, please?  At a guess perhaps rename/delete your Normal.mxt.

Answer (score 1):

Change your screen resolution to something (much) bigger, move the faulty window, set back your screen resolution to what it was

Comment: I have already done it. No success!

Comment: I could fix it.I moved the task bar to the left of my screen and then moved the window.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276994/profile-view-of-arcmap-is-outside-of-screen#comment441475_277017) they fixed this by:

1. moving their task bar to the left of the screen; then
2. moving the window